# Expressão regular que suporte no mínimo duas das quatro condições

Tags: java, regex

Estou a escrever uma expressão regular para a validação de uma password.

Queria saber qual a maneira mais fácil de fazer com que uma expressão regular aceite, **no mínimo**, duas destas condições:

1. Letras maiúsculas
2. Letras minúsculas
3. Caracteres especiais
4. Números

Neste momento, tenho a seguinte expressão regular:

```
"(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%]).{4,20}";
```

em que:

`(?=.*\\d)`: Aceite, no mínimo, um número.
`(?=.*[a-z])`: Aceite, no mínimo, uma letra minúscula.
`(?=.*[A-Z])`: Aceite, no mínimo, uma letra maiúscula.
`(?=.*[@#$%])`: Aceite, no mínimo, um símbolo.
`{4,20}`: Password entre 4 a 20 caracteres.

O problema é que, para que a senha passe neste processo de validação, a password terá que ter **obrigatoriamente** um destes símbolos. Ou seja, uma password terá que ter obrigatoriamente um número, uma letra minúscula, uma letra maiúscula e um símbolo.

O que eu quero é que a password respeite **duas ou mais condições**.

**Exemplo**:

- Uma password com uma letra minúscula e um símbolo é aceite (vai de
  encontro com as duas condições).
- Uma password com uma letra minúscula, uma letra maiúscula e um
  símbolo também é aceite.
- Uma password só com minúsculas não é aceite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essa aqui funciona:

`^(?!^([a-z]+|[A-Z]+|\d+|[\W_]+)$).{4,20}$`

Testes: https://regex101.com/r/G4v9oy/7

Ao entrar no site, no painel ao lado direito, é oferecida também uma explicação detalhada sobre o regex.

EDITADO: Observei algumas coisas desnecessárias e simplifiquei a expressão. O link dos testes foi atualizado.

Comment: Testar com `______`.

Comment: Obrigado, @GuilhermeLautert . Já atualizei a minha resposta para abranger também esses outros caracteres especiais.

Comment: Dica: quando você esta trabalhando com ancoras não a necessidade de polas entre colchetes, `[\d]+` basta `\d+`. Segundo você poderia ter usado apenas `(\W|_)+`. E por curiosidade existe tambem a class posix `[:alnum:]`, ficando `[^[:alnum:]]+`

Answer (score 0):

Tente assim:

```
(?:.*[a-z].*[^a-z])|(?:.*[A-Z].*[^A-Z])|(?:.*[0-9].*[^0-9])|(?:.*[^0-9A-Za-z].*[0-9A-Za-z])
```

Explicação:

- `(?:.*[a-z].*[^a-z])` - Qualquer string que tenha uma letra minúscula em algum lugar seguida por alguma outra coisa que não seja uma letra minúscula.
- `(?:.*[A-Z].*[^A-Z])` - Qualquer string que tenha uma letra maiúscula em algum lugar seguida por alguma outra coisa que não seja uma letra maiúscula.
- `(?:.*[0-9].*[^0-9])` - Qualquer string que tenha um dígito em algum lugar seguido por alguma outra coisa que não seja um dígito.
- `(?:.*[^0-9A-Za-z].*[0-9A-Za-z])` - Qualquer string que tenha um símbolo seguido por alguma outra coisa que não seja um símbolo.

Como símbolo, entendemos algo que não é nem letra maiúscula, nem minúscula e nem dígito.

Todas essas partes são juntadas com o `|`. Ou seja, tem que cair em algum dos casos acima.

Comment: Obrigado pela sugestão, e até entendo a sua lógica. No entanto, não passa nos testes: https://regex101.com/r/FkGrXA/1